# MIPS translator in C++, how to convert to hex

Tags: c++, assembly, hex, converters

I am creating a translator in C++ that accepts MIPS assembly instructions such as "add 1, 2, 3" as in add register 2 and 3 and place the result in register 1. Eventually, I save everything into a string representing the machine code that is supposed to be the output, however I want to display it in hexadecimal format, instead it outputs in decimal

```
    assembly = "000000" + m[3].str() + m[4].str() + m[2].str() + "00000" + funct;
    cout << assembly << endl;
```

The literal output is correct = 00000023100000100000
However I want it to output as = 00430820

Can anyone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Have you ever used [*manipulators*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) when outputting text to e.g. `std::cout`? I also suggest you stop using text for numbers, as it's much harder and cumbersome translating text back and forth than numbers.

Comment: How can it output `00430820` when your string includes more fixed zeros than that?  Anyway, totally agree with the previous comment: get a 32-bit integer and print it as hex the normal way.  (Search for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mix binary, with integers

the encoding for `add s,t,d` in BINARY is

"0000 00ss ssst tttt dddd d000 0010 0000"

so you'd have to concat
"000000" + binary(2) + binary(3) + binary(1) + "00000100000"

where binary(x) is the binary represenation with fix 5 digits

in your case

000000 + 00010 + 00011 + 00001 + 00000100000

=   00000000010000110000100000100000, which converts to

00430820h ("0000"=0, "0000"=0, "0100"=4, "0011" = 3, "0000"=0, "1000"=8, "0010"=2, "0000"=0)

if you take a closer look at the encoding, you see

"000000ssssstttttddddd00000100000"

consists of 4 parts. first is constant which defines the instruction, and 3 are defining the registers to be used

```
   "00000000000000000000000000100000" = 0x00000020
+  "000000sssss000000000000000000000" (which is s left shifted by 21)
+  "00000000000ttttt0000000000000000" (which is t left shifted by 16)
+  "0000000000000000ddddd00000000000" (which is d left shifted by 11)
```

so the easiest way to encode this instruction is:

```
uint32_t i = 0x00000020 + (s<<21)  + (t<<16) + (d<<11);
```

print this in hex, and you get: 00430820

Comment: Thank you so much!!